# Cannot resolve symbol 'parameters' when using SQLCommandBuilder

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I'm trying to fetch a query from the database and I've done the following:

```
public DataTable FetchTasks(string questName, string categoryName)
        {
            const string queryString = @"   SELECT  *
                                            FROM    dbo.Task as t
                                                    INNER JOIN dbo.[Quest] as q
                                                        on q.QuestID = t.QuestID
                                                    INNER JOIN dbo.[Category] as c
                                                        on c.CategoryID = t.CategoryID
                                            WHERE   q.[Description] = @questName
                                                    AND c.CategoryTitle = @categoryName";

            using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questName", questName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryName", categoryName);

                    var table = new DataTable { Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture };

                    dataAdapter.Fill(table);

                    return table;
                }
            }
```

However I'm receiving  an error on the following lines:

```
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questName", questName);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryName", categoryName);
```

That reads:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Parameters'

Where have I gone wrong here? I know the mistake is in where I've added the parameters - but I don't understand enough to know how to correct it.

Comment: Its a guess can you add `adapter.SelectCommand = command;` after `using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, ConnectionString))`?

Comment: cmd is an instance of a SqlCommandBuilder not a SqlCommand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Parameters` collection isn't accessible directly from `SqlCommandBuilder`.

Try replacing the two lines in question with these:

```
cmd.DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questName", questName);
cmd.DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryName", categoryName);
```